# Custom line numbering and using letters in the `\linenum` argument

Tags: eledmac

I am making a document with `eledmac` in which there is one paragraph in prose followed by some text in verse.  I need to have a different format for the apparatus for the prose and for the verse.  For the prose the standard format will work, but for the section in verse I would like to have the number and quarter of the verse marked in the apparatus instead of the line number. (The type of verse I am using has a standard format of four quarters per verse).  For example, if there is a variant in the first quarter of the first verse, in place of the line number in the apparatus there should be "1a", and if there is a variant in the third quarter of the second verse, it should read "2c", etc. "a", "b", "c", and "d" marking the first through fourth quarters of the verse respectively.

I have used the `\linenum` command to try to achieve this, but for some reason it inserts a value for the line number at which the lemma ends, so that instead of reading just "1b" it reads "1b-6", for example.  Also, I am using letters in the `\linenum` argument, so that some errors come up with each instance of this.  There are a pair of errors for each instance; for every `\linenum` argument that contains a letter I get the errors:

`Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   b`

and

`Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   b`

"b" is the letter in this particular `\linenum` argument; i.e. `\linenum{1b}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eledmac}

\begin{document}

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}

\beginnumbering
    \autopar

\noindent Arma virumque cano, Troiae qui \edtext{primus}{\Afootnote{A; primo B}} 
ab oris Italiam, fato profugus, Laviniaque venit litora, multum ille et terris 
iactatus et alto vi superum saevae memorem Iunonis ob iram; \edtext{multa}
{\Afootnote{A; multo B}} quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem, inferretque 
deos Latio, genus unde Latinum, Albanique patres, atque altae moenia Romae.

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{stanza}
Musa, mihi causas \edtext{memora}{\linenum{|1b}\Afootnote{A; memorum B}}, quo 
numine laeso,&
quidve dolens, regina deum tot volvere casus\&
\end{stanza}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{stanza}
\edtext{insignem}{\linenum{|2a}\Afootnote{A; insigni B}} pietate virum, tot adire 
labores&
impulerit. Tantaene animis caelestibus irae?\&
\end{stanza}


\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First problem. If you don't tell it explicitly, \linenum change only the line parameter you specified. There is 7 line parameters : startpage|startline|startsubline|endpage|endline|ensubline|font. In you code, you have (badly) changed onlyt the startline. That why reledmac (you should not use eledmac any more if you can) has keept the end line.
2. Second problem, these parameter should be ONLY numeric, because these are stored in counter, and compared in many time in order to know if we have to print them (for example if you have set reledmac to print line number only the first time). So 1a CAN'T work.

But there is solution 
1) for the quarter, use subline number
2) for the apparence, `\sublinenumberstyle`.

In your case you should create a custom command to call the \linenum easily.

For example :

```
\newcommand{\choiceline}[2]{\linenum{|#1|#2||#1|#2}}
```

And if you want to say "first verse, quarter 2(=b)", do

```
\choiceline{1}{2}
```

Then, the way subline is printed :

```
\sublinenumberstyle{alph}
```

Will print it alphabeticly.

Last, but not least,

```
\let\fullstop\relax
```

Will deleted the dot between line number and subline number.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I didn't end up implementing this solution at that time, but I am now making another edition of Sanskrit verse using the "verse, verse-quarter" labeling convention, and I am able to implement this solution for my new text.