# Custom line numbering in a 2-columned edition using `eledpar`

Tags: polyglossia, indic, reledmac, reledpar

I am making an edition wherein a citation from a verse should be referred to by both the verse's number and the quarter of the verse that it appears in. The number of the verse should be a numeral and the quarter should be referred to by a letter, from 'a' to 'd.'  For example, a citation of the second quarter of the third verse should be referred to in the critical apparatus by '3b'. To accomplish this in a standard edition with only one text using `reledmac` one can alphabetize the sub-line numbers and have them function as the component of the citation in the apparatus that refers to the quarter of the verse.  This has already been explained in an answer to a previous question of mine [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263724/custom-line-numbering-and-using-letters-in-the-linenum-argument/263790#263790).

However, I am making a document in which there are two columns of text using `reledpar`.  For some reason, in the following MWE when I use the solution described above the alphabetization of the sub-line number doesn't operate.

In addition to this, however, in the document I am working on I have text in Sanskrit and Tibetan, and this seems to be impacting the line numbering.  Not only is the sub-line number not alphabetized, it doesn't show up at all!  Below the example with Roman script in which the line number is printed as a numeral, there is an example closer to my document in which for some reason the numbering is functioning properly for the Sanskrit (the first text) but not for the Tibetan (the second text).  In my actual document it does not work for either, even though the MWE provided below and my document contain the same elements.  The second MWE may contain fonts that are not standard, you can get the Sanskrit font, Nakula, [here](http://bombay.indology.info/software/fonts/devanagari/), and the Tibetan font, Jomolhari, [here](https://collab.itc.virginia.edu/wiki/tibetan-script/Jomolhari.html).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}

\begin{pairs}

\begin{Leftside} 

\beginnumbering
    \autopar

\newcommand{\choiceline}[2]{\linenum{|#1|#2||#1|#2}}
    \sublinenumberstyle{alph}
    \let\fullstop\relax

\noindent Arma virumque cano, Troiae qui \edtext{primus}{\Afootnote{A; primo B}} ab oris Italiam, fato profugus, Laviniaque venit litora, multum ille et terris iactatus et alto vi superum saevae memorem Iunonis ob iram; \edtext{multa}{\Afootnote{A; multo B}} quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem, inferretque deos Latio, genus unde Latinum, Albanique patres, atque altae moenia Romae.

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{stanza}
Musa, mihi causas \edtext{memora}{\choiceline{1}{1}\Afootnote{A; memorum B}}, quo numine laeso,&
quidve dolens, regina deum tot volvere casus\&
\end{stanza}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{stanza}
\edtext{insignem}{\choiceline{2}{1}\Afootnote{A; insigni B}} pietate virum, tot adire labores&
impulerit. Tantaene animis caelestibus irae?\&
\end{stanza}

\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside} 

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}

\beginnumbering
    \autopar

\newcommand{\choiceline}[2]{\linenum{|#1|#2||#1|#2}}
    \sublinenumberstyle{alph}
    \let\fullstop\relax

\noindent Arma virumque cano, Troiae qui \edtext{primus}{\choiceline{1}{3}\Afootnote{A; primo B}} ab oris Italiam, fato profugus, Laviniaque venit litora, multum ille et terris iactatus et alto vi superum saevae memorem Iunonis ob iram; \edtext{multa}{\Afootnote{A; multo B}} quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem, inferretque deos Latio, genus unde Latinum, Albanique patres, atque altae moenia Romae.

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{stanza}
Musa, mihi causas \edtext{memora}{\choiceline{1}{1}\Afootnote{A; memorum B}}, quo numine laeso,&
quidve dolens, regina deum tot volvere casus\&
\end{stanza}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{stanza}
\edtext{insignem}{\choiceline{2}{1}\Afootnote{A; insigni B}} pietate virum, tot adire labores&
impulerit. Tantaene animis caelestibus irae?\&
\end{stanza}

\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}

\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
    \setotherlanguage{tibetan}
    \newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Nakula}
    \newfontfamily\tibetanfont{Jomolhari}

\usepackage{geometry}

\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.48\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.48\textwidth} 

\newcommand{\choiceline}[2]{\linenum{|#1|#2||#1|#2}}
    \sublinenumberstyle{alph}
    \let\fullstop\relax    

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}

\begin{Leftside} 

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}

\beginnumbering
    \autopar

\devanagarifont
\begin{sanskrit}
\noindent तत्र \edtext{खलु}{\Afootnote{A; एव B}} भगवान् पुनरपि चन्द्रप्रभं बोधिसत्वमामन्त्रायते स्म॥ तस्मात् तर्हि कुमार बोधिसत्वेन महासत्वेन सर्वधर्मानां महाभिज्ञापरिकर्म परिशोधयितुकेमनायं समाधिः श्रोतव्यः॥

\begin{stanza}
महाभिज्ञापरिकर्म \edtext{अविवादेन}{\choiceline{1}{2}\Afootnote{B; अविवदेन A}} देशितः।&
विवादे यस्तु चरति नोद्गृह्णन् स विमुच्यते॥\&
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
अभिज्ञा तस्य सा प्रज्ञा बोद्धं ज्ञानम् अचिन्तियम्।&
उद्ग्रहे \edtext{य}{\choiceline{2}{3}\Afootnote{B; यो A}} स्थितो भोन्ति ज्ञानं तस्य न विद्यते॥\&
\end{stanza}

\end{sanskrit}

\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside} 

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}

\beginnumbering
    \autopar

\tibetanfont
\begin{tibetan}

\noindent དེ་ནས་ཡང་བཅོམ་ལྡན་འདས་\edtext{ཀྱིས་}{\Bfootnote{A; ཀྱི་ B}}ཟླ་བ་གཞོན་ནུར་གྱུར་པ་ལ་བཀའ་སྩལ་པ། དེ་ལྟ་བས་ན་གཞོན་ནུ་བྱང་ཆུབ་སེམས་དཔའ་སེམས་དཔའ་ཆེན་པོ་ཆོས་ཐམས་ཅད་ལ་མངོན་པར་ཤེས་པའི་བྱི་དོར་བྱ་བ་སྦྱང་བར་འདོད་པས་ཏིང་ངེ་འཛིན་འདི་མཉན་པར་བྱ།

\begin{stanza}
།ཆོས་ཐམས་ཅད་ལ་མངོན་ཤེས་པ། །བརྩོད་པ་\edtext{མེད་པར་}{\choiceline{1}{2}\Bfootnote{A; མེད་པ་ B}}བསྟན་པ་སྟེ།&
།བསྩོད་པ་ལ་ནི་གང་གནས་པའི། །འཛིན་པ་དེ་ནི་མི་ཐར་རོ།\&
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
།མངོན་ཤེས་\edtext{དེ་ཡི་}{\choiceline{2}{1}\Bfootnote{B; དེ་ཡིས་ A}}ཤེས་རབ་ཏེ། །སངས་རྒྱས་ཡེ་ཤེས་བསམ་མི་ཁྱབ།&
།འཛིན་པ་ལ་ནི་གང་གནས་པ། །དེ་ཡི་ཡེ་ཤེས་ཡོད་མ་ཡིན།\&
\end{stanza}

\end{tibetan}

\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}

\end{pairs}

\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: for the first problem, please open an issue on github. `\sublinenumberstyle` was not conceveid for reledpar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two questions. In general you should ask for ONE problem in the some time. But, I will try to answer here.

## First question

The main problem is that your

\newcommand{\choiceline}[2]{\linenum{|#1|#2||#1|#2}}

\sublinenumberstyle{alph}
\let\fullstop\relax

is called in the rightside environment, and so have a local impact. And the notes are inserted outside of rightside environment, in `\Columns`.

You should set it in the preamble. In general, you should make all your set in the preamble.

However, there is a conceptual bug in reledmac :  for the apparence of line in notes, it does not use the setting depending of the column.  For your case it doesn't matter, because you don't really use sub line number, but for many people it could be a bad thing. That why the branch issue400, in github, which I have ask you to try, will change it, and define `\sublinenumberstyleR` which will be the equivalent of `\sublinenumberstyle` for the right side, and `\sublinenumberstyle*` which will be the equivalent for both side.

So:

1. For now, juste move in the preamble.
2. When the next version of reledmac with be released, change `\sublinenumberstyle` to `\sublinenumberstyle*`.

## Second question

The main problem is that tibetan has it own conception of alphabetic representation of number. But, and that is the second point, the default font for the line number is only latin script, and so the number is not printed.

Consequently, if you want to have latin letter as number, just let it know to polyglossia when loading tibetan.

```
\setotherlanguage[numerals=false]{tibetan}
```

There is a second problem, maybe: as I said, the default font of line number in notes is not the same as the main text of the notes. You could want to unify them (but as your notes have not the same font, I don't know).

In this case, do

```
\makeatletter
\Xnotenumfont{\ifledRcol@\tibetanfont\else\devanagarifont\fi}
\makeatother
```

1. \makeatletter/makeatother because we will use command with @
2. \Xnotenumfont is a reledmac command which set the font for the number.
3. \ifledRcol@ let use know if we are in typesetting a right or a left side.